# Seperate numbers with parenthesis across multiple column pairs

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data set with percentages given as decimals and a value inside parentheses in the same cell. How would I split the two values into two separate cells? Could I use separate() from the tidyr package?

Example:

```
Frog          Dog
.12 (0.05)   .14 (0.10)
.12 (0.04)   .44 (0.11)
```

.

```
dput(mydata) 

structure(list(X = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label =  c("Blue", "Green ", "Purple", "Red"), class = "factor"), Green = structure(1:4, .Label = c("", "0.12 (0.05)", "0.14 (0.09)", "0.34 (0.05)"), class = "factor"), Red = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.12 (0.08)", "0.19 (0.05)", "0.42 (0.04)"), class = "factor"), Blue = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.1 (0.04)", "0.14 (0.04)", "0.17 (0.01)"), class = "factor"), Purple = structure(4:1, .Label = c("", "0.15 (0.08)", "0.18 (0.02)", "0.34 (0.05)"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Yes you can use `separate`. Did you try? What went wrong? Can you `dput` the data?

Comment: can you provide the output of `dput(your_data)`?

Comment: I can't do that, I'm not permitted unfortunately. I tried separate(data2, Barking, into = c("heritability", "p-value")) and it separated at the decimal of the first value. how can I get it to separate at the parentheses?

Comment: _"I'm not permitted unfortunately."_ We don't need your actual data, just a `dput` of an example like you posted. We can't read that in easily, and we want the exact same thing that you have.

Comment: I added it to the original post. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `separate` if you give a correct `sep` argument. It's easiest if you reshape your data first:

```
library(tidyverse)

res1 <- mydata %>% 
  gather(color, values, Green:Purple) %>% 
  separate(values, c("heritability", "p-value"), sep = ' ') %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(heritability, 'p-value'), parse_number)
```

Note that we can easily get rid of the parentheses and spaces and other junk, using the `parse_number` function from `readr`. The `separate` call will spew warnings, as you have some empty cells that can't be split.

This gives:

> ```
>         X  color heritability p-value
> 1  Green   Green           NA      NA
> 2     Red  Green         0.12    0.05
> 3    Blue  Green         0.14    0.09
> 4  Purple  Green         0.34    0.05
> 5  Green     Red         0.19    0.05
> 6     Red    Red           NA      NA
> 7    Blue    Red         0.42    0.04
> 8  Purple    Red         0.12    0.08
> 9  Green    Blue         0.17    0.01
> 10    Red   Blue         0.14    0.04
> 11   Blue   Blue           NA      NA
> 12 Purple   Blue         0.10    0.04
> 13 Green  Purple         0.34    0.05
> 14    Red Purple         0.18    0.02
> 15   Blue Purple         0.15    0.08
> 16 Purple Purple           NA      NA
> ```

I would advise you to keep it in this format, for further analysis and plotting. It is "tidy" this way.

If you want it in wide form, you can reshape again:

```
res1 %>% 
  gather(type, value, -X, -color) %>% 
  unite(key, color, type) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

Gives:

```
       X Blue_heritability Blue_p-value Green_heritability Green_p-value Purple_heritability Purple_p-value Red_heritability Red_p-value
1   Blue                NA           NA               0.14          0.09                0.15           0.08             0.42        0.04
2 Green               0.17         0.01                 NA            NA                0.34           0.05             0.19        0.05
3 Purple              0.10         0.04               0.34          0.05                  NA             NA             0.12        0.08
4    Red              0.14         0.04               0.12          0.05                0.18           0.02               NA          NA
```

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect, if you wouldn't mind, how would you recommend plotting this data?

Comment: Perhaps something like `ggplot(res1, aes(X, heritability, fill = color)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')`. It will depend on the biology and the question at hand, so hard to give definitive advice.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  cSplit(names(df)[-1], ' ') %>% 
  mutate_at(-1, parse_number)

#        X Green_1 Green_2 Red_1 Red_2 Blue_1 Blue_2 Purple_1 Purple_2
# 1 Green       NA      NA  0.19  0.05   0.17   0.01     0.34     0.05
# 2    Red    0.12    0.05    NA    NA   0.14   0.04     0.18     0.02
# 3   Blue    0.14    0.09  0.42  0.04     NA     NA     0.15     0.08
# 4 Purple    0.34    0.05  0.12  0.08   0.10   0.04       NA       NA
```

Option 2: (much worse, but requires 1 less package)

```
library(tidyverse)

for(col in names(df)[-1])
  df <- df %>% 
          separate(!!col, into = paste0(col, 1:2), sep = ' ')

df %>% 
  mutate_at(-1, parse_number)

#        X Green1 Green2 Red1 Red2 Blue1 Blue2 Purple1 Purple2
# 1 Green      NA     NA 0.19 0.05  0.17  0.01    0.34    0.05
# 2    Red   0.12   0.05   NA   NA  0.14  0.04    0.18    0.02
# 3   Blue   0.14   0.09 0.42 0.04    NA    NA    0.15    0.08
# 4 Purple   0.34   0.05 0.12 0.08  0.10  0.04      NA      NA
```

Data used:

```
df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Blue", "Green ", "Purple", "Red"), class = "factor"), Green = structure(1:4, .Label = c("", "0.12 (0.05)", "0.14 (0.09)", "0.34 (0.05)"), class = "factor"), Red = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.12 (0.08)", "0.19 (0.05)", "0.42 (0.04)"), class = "factor"), Blue = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.1 (0.04)", "0.14 (0.04)", "0.17 (0.01)"), class = "factor"), Purple = structure(4:1, .Label = c("", "0.15 (0.08)", "0.18 (0.02)", "0.34 (0.05)"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
df
#        X       Green         Red        Blue      Purple
# 1 Green              0.19 (0.05) 0.17 (0.01) 0.34 (0.05)
# 2    Red 0.12 (0.05)             0.14 (0.04) 0.18 (0.02)
# 3   Blue 0.14 (0.09) 0.42 (0.04)             0.15 (0.08)
# 4 Purple 0.34 (0.05) 0.12 (0.08)  0.1 (0.04)
```